# What to do after changing the dual-boot OS?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

So I have Windows Vista & Ubuntu 11.10. Everything is ok, but I want to change change Vista for Seven. What do I need to do in order to get the grub menu to keep working correctly? Edit a file? Just update the Grub? I also want to shrink windows partition and expand ubuntu partition... SO What do I need to do to the grub menu?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For dual booting issue, you can replace Vista with 7. Windows 7 will replace boot menu without entry for Ubuntu. To make ubuntu entry in boot menu, you can use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) which can be downloaded from [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/EasyBCD.shtml).